# date difference in Dbeaver

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, dbeaver

I have 2 date columns, but the data type for these 2 columns are string, not date.
I want to make a difference in terms of months between the two columns.
ex:
col 1       col 2
2021-01-01  2021-03-01
I need to see the difference in months. So 2 months between the 2 dates/columns.

Any help please?

Comment: Dbeaver is just a client, what is your rdbms?

Comment: Thanks. I'm connected to a Data Lake AWS Athena database

Comment: Date calculations in months aren't well-defined, and they tend to be highly application-dependent. How many months between "2020-12-28" and "2021-02-28"? How about "2020-12-31" and "2021-02-28"?

Comment: Indeed, I understand.. I was thinking to round up the result if possible. However back to your point: it's not well defined. Therefore we can do the difference in days. It's ok also. But I can't find a function which can help ..because if Dbeaver or..because of the Data Lake environment. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the flavour of SQL, you need to cast the string values in date type and then you can perform subtraction.
For ex, if you want the difference between two col, try the following query

select (col2::date)-(col1::date) from table_name

Try this and let me know